# How to Check whether a user clicked 'Ok' or 'Cancel' while using Confirm() function?

Tags: javascript

I am using a confirm() function for logging out. How can i check whether the user clicked Ok or Cancel. My confirm function is

confirm('Are You Sure')

But now, while clicking both Ok and Cancel the page redirects. How can I resolve it?

Comment: <a href="#" onclick="logout()" id="logOt">Logout</a> 

function logout()
{
confirm('Are You Sure');
}

Want to check now.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
if (confirm('Are You Sure?')){
   window.location = "http://www.google.com/";
}else{
   alert("You are not redirected.")
}
```

[DOCUMENTATION](http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptconfirm.php)

Answer (score 4):

You need to get the return value of `confirm`, and then decide what to do next.

```
var answer = confirm('Are You Sure');
if (answer) {
   //...
} else {
   //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I experimented with visual studio and on my computer works two ways:

```
if (confirm("Do you want to log out?")) {
       //..
    }
else {
       //..
    }
```

Or:

```
var question = confirm("Do you want to log out?");
if (question == true) {
           //..
        }
    else {
           //..
        }
```